# Jquery UI draggable not appears to be dragged

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Below is my row object in the JQuery Datatables.

```
<tr class="draggableobject ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
    <td>Account</td>
    <td>706986 - M J KELLNER CO INC</td>
    <td>Atlanta</td>
    <td>$36,000</td>
</tr>

$(".draggableobject").draggable();
```

When I drag the row, I cant see the row dragged. Am I doing any thing wrong? I am trying to implement drag and drop from Datatables to a different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in helper as clone. I think this is the only way.
https://jsfiddle.net/qL859az0/

```
$(".draggableobject").draggable({
  helper: "clone"
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.